# How to change font in an application when there is no option in preferences?

Tags: xfce

I have installed an application called [Genius](https://www.jirka.org/genius.html) which has a built in editor, but there is no option in the preferences to change the font (the default font size is very small). I contacted the author who said :

> Right now there is no option there. It uses the standard font that the
> GtkSourceView uses which I think is the standard GNOME monospace font,
> so if you change that in the gnome settings it should also affect
> genius.

However, I'm not using Gnome but Xfce (Xubuntu), and changing the font in settings/appearance/fonts has no effect. I do have other Gnome applications installed (Abiword, Gnumeric), and a google search brought up "gsettings" which can apparently change settings in Gnome applications. gsettings is installed, but I haven't been able to find much info on how to use it. Can I use gsettings to change the font size for Genius, and if so, how? or is there another way?

Comment: Might be worth trying to specify the font in the [gtkrc file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GTK#Basic_theme_configuration).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm afraid it didn't work.

Comment: I've also tried using gnome-tweaks (formerly gnome-tweak-tool) to change the font size, without success.

Comment: When you changed the font in the Appearance dialog, did you try changing the Default Font or just the Default Monospace Font?

Comment: Initially I only changed the Default Monospace font, which didn't work. Changing the Default font (from 9 to 11) does indeed work, but then the menu fonts for all applications are too large for my taste.